# Is there a way to make objects invisible while editing your form in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way to make objects invisible while editing your form in VC# / C#.?

I want to make my image and panel invisible while editing my form in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2015 and even if I make it invisible during edit will I don't want it to stay invisible when the program runs.

Is there any way?
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Errr...set visibility? What am I missing here?

Comment: yea visibility during edit

Comment: winforms, wpf other?

Comment: Why do you need such functionality?

Comment: window formssssssssssss

Comment: Set the visible property.

Comment: @RezaAghaei sometimes it's easier to edit some controls with other controls not being visible (e.g. a control that would go in front of the others).

Comment: @Rariolu those times you can simply `Send to Back` or `Bring to Front` or ... commands :) at least for those times I don't need set visibility of a control.

Comment: @RezaAghaei It just depends on preference really, some people just do things differently. No shame in that ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go into the designer file (a ".cs" file) and find where the particular control is added into the form. e.g:

```
this.Controls.Add(button1);
```

And then you either delete this line or comment it:

```
//this.Controls.Add(button1);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: OP:and even if I make it invisible during edit will I don't want it to stay invisible when the program runs.

Comment: You can change it back once you're done editing. It's what I do, or even move the code from "InitialiseComponent()" to the contructor ("Form1()")

Comment: Rariolu i like the sound of it but i dont understand how to carry it out

Comment: Ahh this works thanks :D (Can accept answer in 4mins)

Comment: This is not a good strategy since an edit in the visual designer will most likely remove your changes. It even says so in the top of the designer file "Do not edit this file".

Comment: @Patrick If you know what you're doing then it's fine. Usually the designer file doesn't remove this particular change.

Comment: Ok patrick i will keep that in mind

Comment: @Rariolu such a strange preference and such a good fit answer +1 ;)